# Tomcat Creates new JSESSIONID even when existing session id provided in the request

Tags: session, tomcat, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, jsessionid

I've a web application deployed on tomcat, integrated with Forgerock for SSO. Intially when users logs into the application using forgerock tomcat creates & returns a new JSESSIONID(for that particular session). But as soon as UI module make some more rest calls(simulatneously when UI is loading after logging into forgerock) to the backend application on the server, tomcat randomly returned a new Session ID in the response.

We're using Tomcat's persistence manager and file storage for the session storage. And following is the configuration done for it.

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" persistAuthentication="true" processExpiresFrequency="1" maxIdleBackup="1">
           <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore" directory="${catalina.base}/temp/sessions"/>
   </Manager>
```

So the main part is why tomcat is returning a new JSESSIONID in the response headers, when the request was made with existing active session.

This behaviour is happening randomly, sometimes it works properly and at times it returns new JSESSIONID.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two web applications. Different web applications will have different `JSESSIONID` cookies.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, we've different web applications. But our cookie path is on root URL i,e. "/". So all the web applications uses same JSESSIONID.

Comment: Distinct applications have distinct `Manager`s: they will not recognise each other's session ids. However you can add a [`SingleSignOn`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/SingleSignOn.html) valve.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, we are using tomcat's persistence manager and persistence valve for this. So we've configured the manager explicitly.